# How to override the pager default top and bottom margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, overriding

It would appear that that bootstrap puts a 10px margin on the top and bottom of the pager and I would like to cut that down to 2px and also make the height of the pager a bit smaller. I'm using the code from the xsnippets.openNTF as follows:

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="repeat1"
    panelPosition="left" styleClass="bootstrapPager">
    <xp:pagerControl type="Previous" id="pagerControl1"
        styleClass="bootstrapPagerPrevious">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[«]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl type="Group" id="pagerControl2"
            styleClass="bootstrapPagerMiddle">
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl type="Next" id="pagerControl3"
        styleClass="bootstrapPagerNext">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[»]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:pagerControl>
</xp:pager>
```

as suggested I created a new css and copied the css from the xsnippets into it and applied it to the page however I don't think that should be necessary with bootstrap built in so I removed the css. The pager works the same either way. So I want to over-ride the bootstrapPager class and change the margins.
I created a new css called it myBootstrap.css and added this block

```
.bootstrapPager {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

and changed the top and bottom margins to 2px. added the css as a resource but the pager margins do not appear to have changed. Maybe there are some other settings that need changing. As I read it this class should override the main bootstrap.css.

EDIT
If I set disable Theme to true then it appears to remove the margins, but then it also removes all of the additional styling and that is no good either.
Here is what the pager looks like (not connected to the repeat yet but that should not matter. The major issue is the amount of vertical space that it consumes. When I inspect the element in Chrome it looks very much like it is getting the values from the main bootstrap css.

[image]

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Also can you create a fiddle. If i had to guess the problem I would say it has something to do with your css selector no being strong enough.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 that is bundled with the XPages 9.0.1 Extension Library.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

Not sure this will work, but please try adding `!important` to your CSS selector. This has worked for me in the past.  In my case it was OneUI, but the concept is the same. This assumes that the style is being applied, but is overwritten.

```
.bootstrapPager {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px !important;
  margin-top: 2px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

For more info, I wrote a blog post on this subject last year when I was having a similar problem: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/10/quick-tip-forcing-css-override.html

Note: I have never had much luck ever trying to us the "disable theme" feature.

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm assuming that the page loads the bootstrap.css first then my over-ride.css but it looks like it might be doing it the other way around. I will take a look at your blog. This is most puzzling, I'm not a css expert by any stretch but as I understand it this is how you over-ride a class in a css.

Comment: I'm assuming the issue has to do with the specificity, but in this case I don't quite understand how to raise the specificity in the over-ride css. I think I might start this as a new question on specificity

Comment: here is the link to my new more specific (pun) queestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593230/how-to-set-the-specificity-of-an-over-ride-class-for-xpages

Comment: Are you using a theme to load your custom CSS last?  I would suggest this to make sure that yours is loaded last. Did you check using Inspect Element that your style .bootstrapPager is definitely applied?

Comment: Not sure how to do that one

Comment: Created a theme myTheme in it I'm assuming that it extends bootstrap but that is not one of the options in the theme text. then uncommented the resources and add myBootstrap.css no change.

Comment: In chrome, select the pager. Select Inspect Element.  With the html generated from the pager selected, look at the 'Styles' tab on the right side.  You will see several likely, see if yours is in the list.  If not applied, then nothing will change.  Worst case, you could edit the bootstrap CSS, but this is not a recommended practice.