# How to set the specificity of a css over-ride class for XPages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, overriding

This starts from a previous question that I asked but I think I know what needs to be done but not the How. I have this block of code that defines a pager in bootstrap and applies the bootstrap style to it:

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="repeat1"
    panelPosition="left" styleClass="bootstrapPager">
    <xp:pagerControl type="Previous" id="pagerControl1"
        styleClass="bootstrapPagerPrevious">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[«]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl type="Group" id="pagerControl2"
            styleClass="bootstrapPagerMiddle">
    </xp:pagerControl>
    <xp:pagerControl type="Next" id="pagerControl3"
        styleClass="bootstrapPagerNext">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[»]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:pagerControl>
</xp:pager>
```

then in a css that I load I have this to over-ride the bootstrap class bootstrapPager:

```
.bootstrapPager {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

The default .bbotstrapPager has a top and bottom margin of 10px and I want to reduce it to 2px. I tried !important but that does not work. I have read a bit about css specificity and I think that is what is the problem is. So in this context how would I go about setting specificity in my .bootstrapPager class so that it ranks higher than the default class?
My css experience is not great but getting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your margins this way:

```
.pagination {
    margin: 0px;
}

.bootstrapPager {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

The pager gets rendered to a `<div>` and an included `<ul>`.
The `<ul>` tag has a css class `pagination` with a margin of 20px on top and bottom.
So, first set those margin to 0px overwriting class `pagination` with your css resource.

Then you can set the margins you like in your css class `bootstrapPager`.

[image: rendered pager]

[image]

Alternatively, you can put all your changes into class `pagination` and omit your class `bootstrapPager`.

Comment: When I inspected the page in chrome and made the changes it responded the way that I wanted it to, but I can't seem to get the changes in the style sheet to over-ride the bootstrap defaults. at the moment I have to move on to something else. It looks OK but is not where I would like it to be. I'll try again tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: The margin is set by `<ul class="pagination">`.  `<ul> ... </ul>` is a block with properties like margin, padding and so on. It is surrounded by a `<div> ... </div>` block which has it's own properties like margin, padding and so on. You can't "overwrite" ul block's properties with your class bootstrapPager because they only "work" on div block. That's why you have to change pagination's properties first.

Comment: Was only added the .bootstrapPager css and missed the .pagination -- added both to my css and now it works great. Still want to make some additional changes to the whay the pager looks but think this gets me going in the right direction.

Comment: Strange the over-ride works fine in Chrome but seems to have no effect in FireFox

Comment: Delete cache in Firefox.